# How to get filesize in client side with JSF richfaces fileupload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces

I am using rich fileupload 4.3.2 version. JSF richfaces fileupload first uploads files on server and then throws the error if file size exceeds in size. Size restriction in web.xml is already put but since its global parameter I can not put a smaller number.

If a user starts uploading file in large size it takes lots of time since upload speed at client side is very slow in KBs (It takes 5-10 mins to upload 25 MB of file).

I am thinking to validate the filesize before its uploaded on server in javascript. In 3.3 version it was possible using event.memo.entry.size. but it’s not available with 4.3.2 version.

I want to find a solution to check filesize in client side using rich fileupload (4.3.2) only since its already been used at many places in my application. Changing to entirely new solution will not be feasible.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to upgrade to Richfaces 4.5 and use the [`maxFileSize` attribute](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.5.X/4.5.17.Final/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-fileUpload-Upload_settings) of the fileUpload component:

Example:

```
<h:form>
    <!-- Max 50.000 bytes -->
    <ri:fileUpload maxFileSize="50000" ... />
</h:form>
```

Files greater thant that won't be added to the upload UI. You should add a text hint regarding the upload limit.

Comment: Upgrade I am aware of. But since project is in maintenance and after upgrade other functionalities stops working. I can not plan upgrade. Any solution with richfaces 4.2?

Comment: @priyam at the time of RF 4.2 it wasn't possible to check the file size on the client side; you'd have to implement that check yourself

Comment: there is no direct way of doing it.. but is there any way to play around with html and css elements and get the file size?

Comment: @priyam well, not through HTML/CSS, you need JavaScript